# jQuery finding TR->TH value(s)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wildcard

Hey all i have the following jquery code here:

```
$('th[id*="headingData_"]').each(function () {
    fieldNames += $(this).data("dbname") + '~';
    console.log(fieldNames);
})
```

And this is the HTML that I'm pulling data from:

```
<tr role="row">
   <th id="headingData_0" data-dbname="F_FName" class="sorting_asc" tabindex="0" 
       aria-controls="theDataTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-sort="ascending" 
       aria-label="First Name: activate to sort column ascending" 
       style="width: 557px;">First Name
   </th>
   <th id="headingData_1" data-dbname="F_LName" class="sorting" tabindex="0"
       aria-controls="theDataTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" 
       aria-label="Last Name: activate to sort column ascending" 
       style="width: 557px;">Last Name
   </th>
   <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="theDataTable" rowspan="1" 
       colspan="1" aria-label="Action: activate to sort column ascending" 
       style="width: 438px;">Action
   </th>
</tr>
```

The jQuery code above does work *but* there are also footer labels of the same name below the table so (in this example) there are 3 headers;

**First Name**

**Last Name**

**Action**

So when I run that it doubles both the **First Name** and **Last Name**. I am trying to find a way to *only get the header labels* and not the footer labels as well.

The footer HTML looks like this:

```
<tr>
    <th id="headingData_0" data-dbname="F_FName" rowspan="1" colspan="1">First Name
    </th>
    <th id="headingData_1" data-dbname="F_LName" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Last Name
    </th>
    <th rowspan="1" colspan="1">Action</th>
</tr>
```

So I am trying to figure out the way in order for me to only query the **tr role="row"** part in order to get those headers and nothing more. The headers may have more than 2 headings at any given time so its not always going to be just 2 headings.

Any help would be great!

Comment: Side note, IDs **must** be unique.

Comment: @j08691 yes thats correct but the jQuery plugin I am using is populating the HTML code you see above for both the header and footer.

Comment: In that case I would suggest maybe not using that plugin as it is obviously badly written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add it to the beginning of your selector:

```
$('tr[role="row"] > th[id*="headingData_"]').each(function () {
    fieldNames += $(this).data("dbname") + '~';
    console.log(fieldNames);
});
```